# How to configure Windows 10 OpenSSH client window size

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh

I am connecting to an **OpenSSH service** installed on a **Windows 10** machine via the **cmd** terminal running on another **Windows 10** machine.

The issue is that, even thought the terminal properties, i.e., the number of rows and columns, is set appropriately before running the ssh command, yet when ssh is executed, **#rows** and **#cols** are set back to the ssh default values [30, 85].

I used **stty cols 150** option on ssh terminal, but it is not affecting. When I run **stty -a** the same values [30, 85] is shown.

Any idea on how to configure the **OpenSSH client** default window size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved after a system reboot!!!